# Django autogenerate POST data dict for arbitrary admin form

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, django-admin

I would like to autogenerate a dictionary of data to POST to a django admin change form, as if the current object is not changing.  Basically simulate the POST request that would happen if you do a GET on the change page from the admin, and then click Save.  This should take into account which fields are editable on that particular change form, and *also be able to handle InlineAdmins.*

```
    def auto_generate_changeform_data(object):
        data = ???
        return data
```

For example, in line 302 of [the django admin testcases](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6c1/tests/admin_inlines/tests.py) they manually create the POST data dictionary, but this is something that should be possible to autogenerate, right?

I would then use this function in a testcase where I want to test what happens when I change one particular field on that model, or even one of the inlines.

```
    #some testcase
    some_object = SomeModel.objects.get(...)
    url = reverse("admin:appname_modelname_change", args=[some_object.id])
    data = auto_generate_changeform_data(some_object)
    data['some_field'] = 'new value'  #this is the only change I want to make
    response = self.client.post(url, data)
```

I could do all of this in a more unit-y fashion by using the methods on the ModelAdmin class instead of going through a POST request to the client, but I want a **functional test** not a unit test in this case.  I actually do want to simulate the full POST to the url.

How can I get this data dictionary, particularly the part about inline formsets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this before by simply doing the GET request with the test client and then using BeautifulSoup to scrape out all the `input` and `select` elements.

It's not completely straightforward because of the different ways those elements represent their values, but [here](https://gist.github.com/simonw/104413) is some code that should work.